# Angular Meteor: Pass parameter to helper function

Tags: function, parameters, helper, angular-meteor

How can I pass a parameter to a helper function?

This was possible with Blaze:

```
Template.dummy.helpers({
    getImage: function(imageId) {
        return Images.findOne(imageId);
    }
});

{{ getImage '1234' }}
```

How can I do something like that with Angular Meteor?

This is not working:

```
this.helpers({
   getImage: (imageId) => {
       return Images.findOne(imageId);
   }
});
```

Comment: How do you call the helper function?

Comment: I tried it like this: `{{ workList.getImage('1234') }}` (workList is the controllerAs name)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `this.helpers`, how is `helpers` attached to `this`? Have not found any angular docs with googling "angular helpers". Don't you mean `this.getImage = (imageId) => Images.findOne(imageId)`? Then this would be accessible in the layouts as `controller.getImage` using the "controller as syntax".

Comment: Also, make sure `Images` is in scope.

Comment: This is angular-meteor (http://www.angular-meteor.com/) and they introduced the helpers in the newest version (I think) to move it closer to the Meteor standard. I found a solution for my problem: I had to two different collection/subscription for Work and Images. And the Images sub was not ready as the img-elements were rendered. Now I have combined the Images and Work into one subscription and with this I can use a normal controller function.

Answer (score 0):

Restating the comment which resolved your issue, make sure `Images` is in scope. If `Images` is fetched in a subscription, it may not be available at the same time `this.getImage` is called.